# A person who is willing and not afraid of taking risks

Tags: word-request

I wonder what do you call a person who is willing to take risks and is not afraid of doing risky things. Such people believe that the success is on the other side of risk, and they have to go through it in order to achieve success. The word in my question should be an exact antonym for "risk-averse".

Answer (score 2):

*Adventurer* or *daredevil*, or perhaps *risk-taker* but that last one sounds a bit mundane (in other words, very ordinary and therefore not interesting).

You can find more possibilities in a good [thesaurus](https://thesaurus.plus/thesaurus/risk_taker) under "risk-taker".

Comment: Yeah I also came up with Daredevil, along with Hotshot / Hotdog. If you search for hotdogging be sure to type as one word: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hotdogging